# Is "gear down" a complex word?

Tags: morphology

I'm not sure. I would say yes since it is a particle verb. If it is could you also tell me with which morphological process it was created ?

Comment: It is what is often called a 'separable phrasal verb', in other words an idiomatic verb + preposition (sic) combination which requires a pronominal object to come between the verb and the preposition. However, as shown by @user, there's little reason to call such verb + preposition idioms 'words'.

Answer (score 0):

In most theories of "word", it is not "a" word, it is a combination of words – a phrase, in the non-technical sense. See for example "I had to gear all the way down" with a phrase between the two elements. Syntactically speaking, this is a multiple-word construction. It may have one thing in common with certain single words, namely an element of semantic unpredictability, just as "look up (the address)" can't be derived from the meaning of "cast your eyes in a direction" plus "upwards". "Gear down" is actually closer to semantic transparency, and is more like "turn the volume down", which derives from a physical action of turning a potentiometer nob in the downward direction (if you're right-handed) in order to decrease the volume. However, I understand that "gear down" has taken on metaphorical uses as well that don't literally involve down-shifting a vehicle.

Comment: I (a native British speaker) did not recognise the phrase _gear down_ at all, and would not have understood it without context. Looking it up in Wiktionary, I found the definition "To arrange a system of gear wheels or pulleys etc such that the driven part rotates or moves slower than the driving part", which makes sense to me, but I would not have thought of it. If I came across _gear down_ in a context which indicated it related to changing gear in a car, I would assume that this was from a non-English speaker.

Comment: When I first read the title I read it as what the copilot says after the landing gear are locked in place on approach. Short for _The gear are down_.